# Database design to send notifications to all users

Tags: postgresql, notifications

I'm searching for a solutions to create a notification and notify to all users, record their reaches and views. We have around tens of thousands users.

If each time of creating a new notification, I need to write records for all the users, the database may be overloaded with a surge in writing processes.

Do you have a better design for this use case? Thank you in advance.

I use PostgreSQL, with those two tables somehow like below.

```
CREATE TABLE notification (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    notification_message VARCHAR(255), 
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE notification_user (
    user_id BIGINT,
    notification_id BIGINT,
    status VARCHAR
)
```

Comment: "Tens of thousands" will present no problem for the database. "Tens of millions" might.

Comment: @Belayer, does it means tens of thousands write process to db concurrently? If so I think it could be an outage...

Comment: With much more detail there is little more to be added. But unless your DB server  is under resourced there should not be much problem. Tnen again there is a quantitative difference between 10K and 90K, and time frames in per hour, per min, or per sec.

Comment: Thank you @Belayer for more suggestions. Let say I have 90k users. In my use case, each time I create a notification, immediately the system needs to create 90k rows of notification_user to record the status of the notification, it may take one or several seconds with the way I currently implement.
That process will take a big workload on DB. Do you have any suggestions to reduce the load operations, e.g how to split the job?

Comment: Are you sure you are using Postgres? Those dreaded backticks are invalid in (standard SQL) and in Postgres. Also: there is no performance or storage advantage by declaring a limit of 255 for a `varchar` column compared to e.g. 250 or 276.

Comment: Hi, a_horse_with_no_name, yes, I'm using Postgres, I just edit a little bit for less confusion. That is just an illustration of the tables, not the real one.

Answer (score 2):

Without a lot more details there is not much anyone can advise you on. But do not dwell over a measly 90K rows. First off I have no idea of your design, but assuming you have normalized you should have 3 tables here: users, notifications, and user_notifications. But put together something and TEST it, that is the only to determine if you actually have an issue of just the presumption of an issue.  
I have put together a small demo.  I like round number so I used 100K users and a simple query to insert a notification as a user_notification for each user. I then ran a that insert 1,2,3,4,5,10, and 25 notification. That results in 100K rows to 2.5M and captured the time. All on my "play machine". This is not a formal performance test just more of a back-of-the-envelope test. 
**Environment**  
Acer laptop with
Intel I5 1.6GHz 4Core 8GB Ram
Windows 10 Home 64bit
Postgres 12.0 
IDE: DBeaver 7.0.0
Overall, a very much underrated server.  
**Results:**

```
 users 100000
  notice    # rows    time (in sec)  
 -------- --------- --------------- 
       1    100,001          1.750  
       2    200,002          3.781  
       3    300,003          5.500  
       4    400,004          7.663  
       5    500,005          9.367  
      10  1,000,010         21.186  
      25  2,500,025         60.6  

# rows includes notifications + user_notifications inserts
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=22e7728ed4d283e89d1e54cdde8d324e) for full sample, but it has only 100 users not 100K. I don't know what performance your server can provide, should be more than my toy.

Comment: Hi Belayer, you are correct. Your answer gives me another point of views, maybe it is just my assumptions, I will do more test. I am wondering how the IOPS is count, may be it is not the number of rows to be written in the db is counted.

Comment: All is ok, You sometimes get an idea in you head and just cannot shake it. Been there, done that!  But I do not the acronym  IOPS stands for.